# extjs combobox does not update after store load

Tags: combobox, extjs4, store

In my MVC application I have a controller defined like this:

```
Ext.define('NE.controller.MyController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores : [...'StoreAgents'..],

    views: [ ...'MyView'...], // * alias w_view

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'w_view': {
                render: function() { this.getStore('StoreAgents').load(); }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And in the view MyView I have a combobox defined like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    name : 'id_agent',
    forceSelection: true,
    fieldLabel: 'Agent',
    store: 'StoreAgents',
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id'
}
```

I would expect combobox list to be updated every time the view is rendered, am I wrong?
Currently the combobox remains with no options, even if I see (through firebug) that the application fires the request which correctly returns all agents data.

Furthermore, I noticed that whenever I browse through another view, managed by another controller, which in turn declares another StoreAgent and calls its load() method.. well, if I come back, now I see the combobox populated.

What I am missing?
Thank you

**Edit:**
I noticed that the store is `{buffered: true}`. If I switch it to false, then the store fires the 'datachange' event; otherwise it does not. So the question now is: why if buffering is enabled the load() does not fire 'datachange'?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a filtered out situation.  If the combobox is being filled with a value before the store loads, a filter will be put on the store that filters out all the values before they exist, and then when new records are added they are not displayed either.  Try this.

```
init: function() {
        this.control({
            'w_view': {
                render: function() { this.getStore('StoreAgents').load(); 
                this.getStore('StoreAgents').clearFilter();}
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but still I can't get it work. Looking at firebug the load() method fires the very first ajax request of the application; thus it is unlikely that store has previous filters set on.